# Datastax C# driver 3.3.0 deadlocking on connect to cluster?

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

To Datastax C# driver engineers:

C# driver 3.3.0 is deadlocking while calling to `Connect()`. The following code snippet on Windows Forms will deadlock trying to connect:

```
    public void SimpleConnectTest()
    {
        const string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        const string keyspace = "somekeyspace";

        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
        queryOptions.SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.One);

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder()
            .AddContactPoints(ip)
            .WithQueryOptions(queryOptions)
            .Build();

        var cassandraSession = cluster.Connect(keyspace);

        Assert.AreNotEqual(null, cassandraSession);

        cluster.Dispose();
    }
```

Deadlocking happens here:

```
Cluster.cs -> 
private void Init()
{
  ...
TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(_controlConnection.Init(), initialAbortTimeout);
  ...
}
```

I have tested this on Cassandra 3.9.0, CQL spec 3.4.2 on local machine.

Everything deadlocks on calling this method _controlConnection.Init() here:

```
task = Id = 11, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

This then just runs for 30000ms and throws this:

```
                throw new TimeoutException(
                    "Cluster initialization was aborted after timing out. This mechanism is put in place to" +
                    " avoid blocking the calling thread forever. This usually caused by a networking issue" +
                    " between the client driver instance and the cluster.", ex);
```

Running same test on 3.2.0 has no such problems. Can anyone else test this? Maybe this just happens to me.

Edit:

Here is the screenshot for the deadlock:

[image: Deadlocked tasks with blocking awaiting ()]

Comment: Is this in a console application? Web application? Web forms app?

Comment: This happens on Windows Forms app, Windows Service and IIS app. All running on Windows Server 2012 R2. Also tested it on my local machine with Windows 10. All is written for .NET Framework 4.5.2 .

Comment: From your explanation, what you are experiencing is not a deadlock: the calling thread is not blocked forever (it throws an exception after a long while). To understand what is happening under the hood, you should enable [driver logging](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.3/faq/#how-can-i-enable-logging-in-the-driver).

Comment: To understand what could be the underlying cause for the task returned by `ControlConnection.Init()` to don't run to completion, you should enable the driver logs. I'm not able to reproduce it locally, there are also hundreds of integration tests currently running on win/linux on CI servers that create a new session and they are successfully passing... we need as much info you can give us to understand what could be affecting in your case. Could you create a ticket with that info: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/CSHARP/issues

Comment: jorgebg are you doing integration tests on server that has single CPU?

Comment: @jorgebg also from the screenshot you can clearly see:
1) Tasks have been waiting to run for 3500 miliseconds
2)  There are NO tasks running

Comment: @jorgebg calling thread is blocked by line 153 in the screenshot. That line is called from Cluster.Init() with task created by _controlConnection.Init(). When task from called method comes to that line it is stuck in Status = WaitingForActivation, if you look at MSDN for explanation on this status you will see that it is status when task is being blocked. Also see this url: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the details in your comments, we were able to identify the underlying issue.

[Similar to what was proposed by Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533105/208683), there were some missing `ConfigureAwait()` calls.

This issue impacts users that are calling `Cluster.Connect()` on environments with `SynchonizationContext` which is not a common use case:

- For Windows Forms, its unlikely to communicate directly to a database (without a service in the middle). Furthermore, users should call `Connect()` before creating a form (where there is no `SynchonizationContext`) to share the same Session instance across all forms.
- For ASP.NET, users should call `Connect()` outside of any endpoint action, before the HttpContext is created (where there is no `SynchonizationContext`).

Note that this issue affects only `Connect()` calls. Other blocking calls like `Execute()` don't have this issue.

In any case, this issue could be a showstopper for users getting started with the driver, for example, users creating a simple windows forms app to try a concept.

I've submitted a pull request with the fix, which also contains a test that looks into the source code for the usage of `await` without `ConfigureAwait()` calls to avoid having this issue in the future:
https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/pull/309

You can expect the fix to land in the next patch release.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem, but I suspect the problem might be with a [recent change](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/commit/f21280e4a1bb376596278ddd023e735d7029a996) to make the connection process asynchronous internally. I don't know for sure, but tracing through the `Connect` code, I suspect it might be a missing `ConfigureAwait(false)`. In particular, it looks like the `Reconnect` method (which could definitely get hit as part of that `Init` code path) [is missing one after that commit](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/commit/f21280e4a1bb376596278ddd023e735d7029a996#diff-1d2eadc1327b7b672269da55780fbcf4R260). It's possible that I'm not able to reproduce it because I'm not hitting the `Reconnect` code path while for some reason you are in your environment.

I'm not 100% sure that's the culprit, but I [opened a PR](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/pull/308) to fix it. Stephen Cleary wrote a [great explanation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on why this can happen in Forms/Web apps. You could try building the driver from my fork to see if that change fixes the problem, or wait and see what happens with the PR and a new release. If it's still happening, I'd suggest opening an issue on the [JIRA](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/CSHARP/issues/CSHARP-307?filter=allopenissues).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Still experiencing the problem. I have no experience with using JIRA so I am unsure what and how to post there. I will keep posting here and on github though.

Comment: The JIRA for this driver can be found here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/CSHARP/summary
It requires a simple account setup to create a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been opened here with workaround:

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/CSHARP/issues/CSHARP-579

For anyone experiencing the same - just wrap your connection code into a new task.

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        SimpleConnectTest();
    });
```

Comment: The 3.3.1 version of the driver have a fix for this issue.